# Can I select which elements appear on the Stack Overflow for Teams Question/Answer screen?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-for-teams

The SO for Teams UI feels a little cluttered (I have no use for the 4 outlined elements).

Perhaps these elements could be made toggleable on/off on a per-user basis from a UI customisation page?

[image]

#### Afterthought

I used [ublock origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm?hl=en) to hide the extraneous elements, it feels much less congested!

[image]

---

Unrelated: is there a meta for SO for Teams? (it would probably be the appropriate place for this question, but I couldn't locate it).

Comment: One minor thing I noticed is that when posting, SO for Teams doesn't give a preview as every other SE site does.

Comment: FYI, based on [Catija's answer](/a/362536) (although it's not official) to [Should Stack Overflow for Teams be on topic on meta SE?](/q/362494), since you're not asking anything about the left navigation, it seems your question perhaps should have been posted on [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com) (Meta Stack Overflow) instead. Note that I believe this also answers your last question, i.e., "is there a meta for SO for teams".

Comment: @JohnOmielan Note that after scope changes on MSO, Teams questions are no longer accepted there - instead, one should open a ticket with Teams support as detailed in our [help center page on scope](/help/on-topic).

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Thanks for the info about that update. I now recall reading something about that change occurring.

Comment: I *personally* disagree and feel like a public Q&A space for these questions would be a good thing. But SE does some *strange* things.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek FWIW I asked for a Teams meta site ([here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424308/5783745)).

Comment: @JourneymanGeek approximately 1h 30m after asking, the question was deleted (!). A reason was not given.